# Using FieldMethodizer to access static files prints "Could not add x for field methodizing: x"

Tags: java, apache, velocity

When I try to use velocity's `FieldMethodizer` variable in my template it prints error.

I'm using SparkJava framework and velocity template engine.

```
    public static String render(Map<String, Object> model, String templatePath) {
        model.put("WebPath", new FieldMethodizer("Path.Web"));
        return strictVelocityEngine().render(new ModelAndView(model, templatePath));
    }

    private static VelocityTemplateEngine strictVelocityEngine() {
        VelocityEngine configuredEngine = new VelocityEngine();
        configuredEngine.setProperty("runtime.references.strict", true);
        configuredEngine.setProperty("resource.loader", "class");
        configuredEngine.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
        return new VelocityTemplateEngine(configuredEngine);
    }
```

I get  error

```
Could not add Path.Web for field methodizing: Path.Web
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `model.put` line to `model.put("WebPath", new FieldMethodizer(new Path.Web()));` to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to model the **full class name** as `com.package.Path` when using [FieldMethodizer](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/app/FieldMethodizer.html)

> context.put("runtime", new FieldMethodizer( "org.apache.velocity.runtime.Runtime" ));

And then use in template `$WebPath.Web`

> and then in your template, you can access any of your static fields in this way :
>
> ```
> $runtime.COUNTER_NAME
> ```